# Git Command Line Tool Not Installed Windows

Tags: git, cordova, jenkins

I'm using a VM as a build machine for a cordova packager that is pulling a cordova plugin from git to add to the app. I have installed git on the vm and added it to the path.

When it tries to add the plugin from git I get the error in the jenkins console:

```
Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to help jenkins find the git file, I can remote on to the vm and run git commands from the command line fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out what the issue was. Whoever set up the jenkins slave in the first place created the PATH in the config page, so the PATH it was using had nothing to do with the path on the actual build machine, and changing that had no effect on where it looked for the git installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the Git installation on your Jenkins server (in the global configuration for the Master, or on the slave configuration):

[image]

(my example is for Linux but it's the same principe for Windows)

Please confirm it solves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Sorry, but, for real, close your console and open it again so the path get updated. It may help.